# Db2 : decimal column to varchar column

Tags: sql, database, db2

My db2 version is 9.5:

I have a select query as below:

```
select sum(BAL_BOOK_AMT) as sum from mySchema.myTable group by idCol
```

This results as below:

```
  SUM
---------
 0
 2,475,000
 746,966.091
-627,247.63
```

I want to use this query as below:

```
insert into mySchema.myTable1 select sum(bal_book_amt) as sum from mySchema.myTable group by idCol
```

However, the SUM column in mySchema.myTable1 is of type VARCHAR(40) (which I can not change to decimal because of other reasons). Because of which I am getting below error:

```
 by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.nm: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-408, SQLSTATE=42821
```

When I try the following:

```
select char(sum(BAL_BOOK_AMT)) as sum from mySchema.myTable group by idCol
```

the values becomes:

```
00000000000000000000000000000.00 
00000000000000000000000000000.00 
00000000000000000000002475000.00 
00000000000000000000000550000.00 
00000000000000000000000746966.09
```

which I do not want.

How can I format such that the values comes as String as is:

```
 0
 2,475,000
 746,966.091
-627,247.63
```

Thanks for reading!

Comment: ... _why_ can't you change it?  Things shouldn't usually be formatted until they're to be displayed - at most I'd remove leading zeroes; thousands separators are different in different regions, for example (and some cultures separate on different units, too).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [VARCHAR_FORMAT() function](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref%2Fsrc%2Ftpc%2Fdb2z_bif_varcharformat.htm)

```
insert into mySchema.myTable1 
select VARCHAR_FORMAT(sum(bal_book_amt), '999,999,999,999.99') as sum
....
```

Comment: This function is not present in my version it seems.. must be a part of a later patch or something.. I do not have control over it..